# Android kotlin plurals

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I'm using polish language in my app. The problem with that is that we have multiple plural forms.
Is there a way to include logic in plural expression such as `>4 -> Produktów` or do I have to do this manually like this:

```
<plurals name="productCount">
<item quantity="two" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
<item quantity="three" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
<item quantity="four" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
<item quantity="other" formatted="true">Produktów</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android Documentation on plurals](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals), the full set supported by Android is zero, one, two, few, many, and other.

So you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="productCount">
        <item quantity="one" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
        <item quantity="two" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
        <item quantity="few" formatted="true">Produkty</item>
        <item quantity="other" formatted="true">Produktów</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that plurals take language from system language settings, so while testing that solution for other languages than english - better make sure that your phone/tablet/oven is set to the desired language. (in this case polish).

If not, "few" quantity will be ignored.